Shouldn't `comment-region`/`uncomment-region` preserve TABs?
As Perl isn't very smart indicating where the actual syntax error is (especially when a semicolon or a closing parenthesis is missing), I had commented larger parts of the added code, just to help finding where the syntax error is (and uncommented it again once I had located and fixed the error).
Some time later when committing using Git, I got some "white space error" warning (i.e. a TAB following a space at the beginning of a line) that I could not explain.
Having had a similar situation today (closing parenthesis was missing), I realized that after uncomment-region (the same region that was commented using comment-region before) there was again a white space error inside that region.
So the question is: Should a combination of comment-region and uncomment-region preserve the TABs (and is it a bug if not), or is that expected behavior?
In the latter case I think comment-region and uncomment-region are rather useless (and I'd prefer using query-replace-regex to replace ^ with # (and later ^#with the empty string).
The docs for my version of Emacs (24.3.1) says: for comment-region:

By default, the `comment-start' markers are inserted at the
current indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on
each line (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the
comment and blank lines do not get comments).  This can be
changed with `comment-style'.

And for uncomment-region:

Uncomment each line in the BEG .. END region.
The numeric prefix ARG can specify a number of chars to remove from the emacs-vercomment markers.

When I tried to reproduce the issue, it did not happen always.
More Details
As I had been asked about the setting of indent-tabs-mode, here is what Emacs responded to C-h v i n d e <tab> t <tab> <return> (display variable indent-tabs-mode):
indent-tabs-mode is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is t

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate `booleanp'.

...


What's the question? Is it really "shouldn't..."? If so, it should be closed because it encourages opinion-based answers. If not, it's not clear.

How to report bugs in Emacs

24.3.1 is very old (11 years) at this point.  If you can't test on a current version of Emacs, please add a recipe (with the example code) for reproducing the issue, which other people could test with.

@phils Probable a better indicator than the age of my Emacs would be a changelog for the related packages. Also what makes it hard to verify is reproduction: As I said I typically try a kind of "bisecting my source" when Per reports some syntax error I cannot spot immediately. Maybe then there are some unbalanced or mismatches parentheses, and Emacs tried to re-indent, actually causing the problem. It seems it seeds something non-trivial to reproduce, unfortunately. Also my Emacs version is still maintained (in SLES 12); the package was built on "Tue Jul  2 10:46:19 2024".

"non-trivial to reproduce" -- you mean you don't always get the same result when starting with the same same text?

I wished I had saved the text when the problem was created, but I did not (my thoughts were all about fixing the white space errors after I had fixed the syntax errors). (I'm using 99% of Emacs' indent suggestions, but in rare cases I indent differently)

Do you have C-hv indent-tabs-mode enabled in that buffer?
Commenting a region involves (or at minimum may involve) indenting things, which will take indent-tabs-mode into account.
(And if that's not enabled, but you want tabs in that buffer's indentation, then maybe something is already amiss with your config.)

indent-tabs-mode: "Its value is t"

Righto.  Please add that information to the question and comment here again when you've done that, and I'll delete this answer.  (Please be explicit in your update that you used C-h v indent-tabs-mode in the same buffer which has the problem, so that it's clear there's no mistake.)

Verified and added.

Heh.  I meant be explicit about the current buffer at the time you did that (confirming it was the buffer with the problem), not to be explicit about the key strokes you used to type the command.  (It doesn't matter how you call describe-variable, but it does matter which buffer is current at the time you do it.)

I ran the command from the Perl mode buffer with the program in question in it, but as I didn't know a better way to display what I had entered ("history"), I used the view-lossage command ;-)

I think you'd agree that C-h v indent-tabs-mode is much, much clearer than C-h v i n d e <tab> t <tab>.  Anyhow, please update the question text to include that clarification about the buffer (so that this information isn't only in a comment to an answer that I'm wanting to delete!), then I can delete my answer.
